# Replacing a string inside a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have strings in my application that users can send via a form, and they can optionally replace words in that string with replacements that they also specify. For example if one of my users entered this string:

```
I am a user string and I need to be parsed.
```

And chose to replace `and` with `foo` the resulting string should be:

```
I am a user string foo I need to be parsed.
```

I need to somehow find the starting position of what they want to replace, replace it with the word they want and then tie it all together.

Could anyone write this up or at least provide an algorithm? My PHP skills aren't really up to the task :(

Thanks. :)

Comment: For future reference, the best part of php is how you can do Google searches in the form `site:php.net [what you want to know]`, so (for example) you can quickly find out how to replace a string by searching <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aphp.net+replace+string">`site:php.net replace string`</a>. Not that it's a bad question, but you can get answers more quickly.

Comment: And apparently this site doesn't like links in comments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\band\b/i', 'foo', $subject);
```

will find all occurences of `and` where it's a word on its own and replace it with `foo`. `\b` ensures that there is a word boundary before and after `and`.

Comment: If the user is choosing the words to find/replace, you should use `preg_quote($find, "/")` to make sure they don't break the regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). You don't need to think so hard about this though you will have to learn a little bit about regexes. :)

Comment: Regexes are TOTALLY worth it though.  This is the answer you need.  Take the time up front to read a little about them and how they work.  You'll be able to use it for a lot of surprisingly cool things!

Comment: Haha yeah they are. I think regexes changed my life. That might be a little weird...

Comment: It would be an idea to have a callback inside the regex to work out what word to replace it with. The complex bit is creating a regex that matches words assuming.people,dont.talk.-entering sentences+like this. I mean, you still understood that, right? ;-)

Comment: For the example given however, I think regular expressions is a bit overkill. A simple str_replace would do the job.

Comment: That's probably true, but it would be a good idea to learn both. preg_replace will allow you to do much more complex things and when you decide that str_replace no longer fits what you needed it to do initially you'll know preg_replace and you'll start to get a feeling for where they both apply.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), or for more complex replacements on Regular Expressions and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Examples for both:

```
<?php
$str = 'I am a user string and I need to be parsed.';
echo str_replace( 'and', 'foo', $str ) . "\n";
echo preg_replace( '/and/', 'foo', $str ) . "\n";
?>
```

---

In response to the comments of this answer, note that both examples above will replace *every* occurrence of the search string (`and`), even when it happens to be within another word.

To take care of that you either have to add the word separators to the `str_replace` call (see the comment of an example), but this will get quite complicated when you want to take care of all common word separators (space, commas, dots, exclamation marks, question marks etc.).

An easier to way to fix this problem is to use the power of regular expressions and make sure, the actual search string is not found within another word. See Tim Pietzcker's example below for a possible solution.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: `echo str_replace( ' and ', ' foo ', $str ) . "\n";`

Comment: @Brendan: "But what if he tries that (and it still doesn't work)?" :)

Comment: Well, fair enough; if you look at it and want to replace word-wise ;) I'll add something to my answer to take care of that :)